# different types of DLLs on windows platform

Tags: .net, c++, dll, com

There are several type of dlls found on windows platform

1. Old style native dll
2. COM dll
3. .NET dll

Are there any more dll types that I am missing in list above? Also what is the difference between each of these?

TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you disregard what a DLL is used for, then there's only one type of 32-bit DLL.

It has PE (Portable Executable) format, and it exports functions and data, plus resources.

If you distinguish between different kinds of content, then there are an unbounded number of different "types" of DLLs. For example, a DLL might contain just resources for a program. Or it might contain bytecode for some interpreter (a .NET DLL is an example of that). Or whatever. E.g., if you're most keen on those with direct support in Windows, a control panel applet is a DLL, a COM type library is a DLL, and a shell namespace extension is usually a DLL, which leads you into distinguishing between different kinds of COM DLLs as "types" of DLLs. As they used to say, it's only limited by your imagination, and by your notion of "type"  --  whatever that notion is.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: .NET DLLs actually do get special handling from Windows, I believe.  All the rest are, as you say, just specific examples of PE DLLs.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: which special treatment would that be? To me it seems that behavior comes from the .NET CLR (mscoree.dll), or Mono. For registered COM DLLs, I know that Windows can host them in a proxy process and marshall interfaces. That definitely is special handling; normal DLLs don't get it.

Comment: @MSalters: Special handling of proxy DLLs come from the COM API, which is just a library distributed with Windows, arguably part of the OS and arguably not.  .NET modules, on the other hand, get different behavior from the OS loader (for WinXP and later), which is how pure-MSIL assemblies can load into a process with different bitness.

Comment: @Ben Voight: Almost. The special .NET treatment started with Windows Server 2003. The first client OS with special treatment was Vista. For Windows XP, mscoree.dll provides all the .NET handling. I believe that the 'special treatment' was basically optimizations, but there might be more to it; this is not really my area.

Comment: @Euro: Maybe not XP RTM, but added in a service pack?  The OS loader integration is required to make `AnyCPU` work.